# How to remove the last empty line of UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview

For some reason, UITextView produces an empty line at the end which causes it to be scrollable for nonsense when the text actually fits perfectly into the bounds.

I figured out that this additional space added to the bottom of the text in the contentView of UITextView is almost exactly the font size. So it is an additional line of text.

I want to remove that line so the UITextView is not scrollable when there is no reason to scroll.

`editable` is set to NO.

I tried setting the contentSize property with a reduced height but this has no effect.

**The string has no whitespace or return character at the end. It comes from UITextView. Tested with a lot of different strings.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try altering the `contentInset` property and set the bottom inset to `-10`. I personally think it would be a hack but it worked when I tested it so just check what the correct inset would be.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.text = [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whiteSpaceAndNewLineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: There's absolutely no newline or whitespace character. It comes from a very long @"verylongstring" without \n or whatsoever... It's a bug in UITextField that causes a new line for nothing.

Comment: I only see this on iOS 4. In any case I think the space is added to make room for the autocomplete suggestions. Take a look at http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms for more details and a possible solution.